# Postgres - Importing multiple rows with Foreign key constraint

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, insert, pgadmin

I can't seem to find an answer for my problem, maybe I'm not asking the right question but here it goes:

I have basically two tables in pgAdmin, let's say `student` and `grades`, eventually with a foreign key constraint (student_id referencing student(id)

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    id CHAR(2),
    name CHAR(4),
PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE grade (
    student_id CHAR(2),
    grade INT,
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student(id));
```

What I'd like to do is copy/import two files into the databases. All good for students but my `grade.csv` files will contain non-existing student IDs and I want the import to ignore and not insert them. Instead of that, the command fails, nothing is imported.

What would be a correct and efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to this problem is the one that one uses quite often when importing data: to use a staging table.

Let's say you have a CSV with two fields (`student_id` and `grade`).  This maps to the `grade` table nicely, and the only problem is the nonexistent students.  So, first create a temporary table and then import the data there:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_grade AS 
    SELECT * 
      FROM grade WHERE FALSE;
```

Then you have multiple options, but the gist of it is only picking the rows from the temp table that have a matching student:

```
INSERT INTO grade
SELECT * 
  FROM tmp_grade
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM student WHERE id = student_id);
```

And done.  The performance of this depends on the size of the data (not surprisingly).  The definitions of the unique `student.id` suggests this won't be the case.  However, if it happens, you can still play around with other variations to the same theme.

**Notes:**

- choosing `char(2)` as the student ID is interesting.
- pgAdmin is a client to PostgreSQL, it does not have tables by itself.

Comment: `char(2)` is an interesting choice indeed, as it will greatly limit the possible number of students (1296?).

Comment: @s.m. Well, I was careful not to say this, as the number of possible characters in UTF8 is quite high ;)

Comment: Ah, true :) Still, there must be a pretty compelling requirement to make it `char(2)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought there would something more elegant but i will probably use this

Comment: Well, you possibly could use `file_fdw` to spare the import, but I haven't tried this approach yet.

Comment: it's more the nested query that bugs me. My table has a lot of student actually. The char(2) was only for the example

Comment: @antoine1111 well, try it first and see if it is good enough.  If not, you can still ask a new question if necessary.